# How to send alert as array in ios push notifications in php

Tags: php, ios, arrays

I have one news articles  website. i am sending newly created article as notification to mobile devices. In that single message it contains post id, post title and post url.  For android it is working fine but in ios array message is not working. in single notification i want to send 3 values at a time.
My code is

```
$passphrase = 'aabb';
$badge = 4;
$ck=realpath("ck.pem");

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $ck);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);


$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);  

if (!$fp)
{
    echo "Failed to iOS connect: $err $errstr";
    //exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
}

$deviceToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyy";  

    $json['post_id'] = "1234";
    $json['post_title']="Test post title";
    $json['post_url']="http://abc.in/news";
    $json['cat_name']="News";

$message= $json; //test news message notification

$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'Default',
'badge' => $badge
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);


// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered '.$msg. PHP_EOL;
```

here when i give messge value as single value then it is working fine. but when i give message value as array  then notifications are not going. 
Please help me how to send array message as notification to ios devices

Comment: Seems to us that the APNS is down.

Comment: i couldn't understand. this format is ok or not?